# jqgrid like dataGrid to be use in Zurb Foundation

Tags: jqgrid, zurb-foundation

I start using Zurb foundation and I need a dataTAble like jqgrid to display data in tabular format which has pagination and ability to select the rows.

I googled allot but found only datatables.net, which is not quite promising for zurb foundation.

Please advise.